# Want To Have Other Language Font(Hindi) In Response Through JSON Using RESTful Web Service

Tags: java, json, web-services

I have a code which on the basis of its url search the database and produce related results.
It was working perfect when the data in database was in english but when i replaced it with my language(HINDI) it started producing garbage encodes. The JSON response generated from my method is producing the required data perfectly but the browser is not showing it in proper way(In HINDI)....

```
**`Returned JSON String`** =
 "{"Emp":{"3":{"EXPERIENCE":"०","Name":"राहुल शर्मा","PROFILE":"ट्रेनी","AGE":"२५","ADDRESS":"घ्हशिअबद","ID":"103","PHONE NUMBER":"८२७३६४५५१०","array":["name","Lamis"]},"2":{"EXPERIENCE":"०","Name":"कुशल सेठ","PROFILE":"ट्रेनी","AGE":"२४","ADDRESS":"नेव देल्ही","ID":"102","PHONE NUMBER":"९१८२७३६४५०","array":["name","Lamis"]},"1":{"EXPERIENCE":"+१","Name":"अजय रण","PROFILE":"देसिग्नेर","AGE":"२७","ADDRESS":"देल्ही","ID":"101","PHONE NUMBER":"७८९९८७६५५६","array":["name","Lamis"]},"0":{"EXPERIENCE":"+१","Name":"राज सिंघ","PROFILE":"देवेलोपेर","AGE":"२६","ADDRESS":"घ्हशिअबद","ID":"100","PHONE NUMBER":"९९८८७७६६५५","array":["name","Lamis"]},"4":{"EXPERIENCE":"०","Name":"रेने रे","PROFILE":"ट्रेनी","AGE":"२३","ADDRESS":"नेव देल्ही","ID":"104","PHONE NUMBER":"८१८२८३८४८५","array":["name","Lamis"]}},"Employee Details":[{"EXPERIENCE":"+१","Name":"राज सिंघ","PROFILE":"देवेलोपेर","AGE":"२६","ADDRESS":"घ्हशिअबद","ID":"100","PHONE NUMBER":"९९८८७७६६५५","array":["name","Lamis"]},{"EXPERIENCE":"+१","Name":"अजय रण","PROFILE":"देसिग्नेर","AGE":"२७","ADDRESS":"देल्ही","ID":"101","PHONE NUMBER":"७८९९८७६५५६","array":["name","Lamis"]},{"EXPERIENCE":"०","Name":"कुशल सेठ","PROFILE":"ट्रेनी","AGE":"२४","ADDRESS":"नेव देल्ही","ID":"102","PHONE NUMBER":"९१८२७३६४५०","array":["name","Lamis"]},{"EXPERIENCE":"०","Name":"राहुल शर्मा","PROFILE":"ट्रेनी","AGE":"२५","ADDRESS":"घ्हशिअबद","ID":"103","PHONE NUMBER":"८२७३६४५५१०","array":["name","Lamis"]},{"EXPERIENCE":"०","Name":"रेने रे","PROFILE":"ट्रेनी","AGE":"२३","ADDRESS":"नेव देल्ही","ID":"104","PHONE NUMBER":"८१८२८३८४८५","array":["name","Lamis"]}],"Employee":[{"EXPERIENCE":"+१","Name":"राज सिंघ","PROFILE":"देवेलोपेर","AGE":"२६","ADDRESS":"घ्हशिअबद","ID":"100","PHONE NUMBER":"९९८८७७६६५५","array":["name","Lamis"]},{"EXPERIENCE":"+१","Name":"अजय रण","PROFILE":"देसिग्नेर","AGE":"२७","ADDRESS":"देल्ही","ID":"101","PHONE NUMBER":"७८९९८७६५५६","array":["name","Lamis"]},{"EXPERIENCE":"०","Name":"कुशल सेठ","PROFILE":"ट्रेनी","AGE":"२४","ADDRESS":"नेव देल्ही","ID":"102","PHONE NUMBER":"९१८२७३६४५०","array":["name","Lamis"]},{"EXPERIENCE":"०","Name":"राहुल शर्मा","PROFILE":"ट्रेनी","AGE":"२५","ADDRESS":"घ्हशिअबद","ID":"103","PHONE NUMBER":"८२७३६४५५१०","array":["name","Lamis"]},{"EXPERIENCE":"०","Name":"रेने रे","PROFILE":"ट्रेनी","AGE":"२३","ADDRESS":"नेव देल्ही","ID":"104","PHONE NUMBER":"८१८२८३८४८५","array":["name","Lamis"]}]}"


**And Browser Visible String** =
"{"Emp":{"3":{"EXPERIENCE":"à¥¦","Name":"à¤°à¤¾à¤¹à¥à¤² à¤¶à¤°à¥à¤®à¤¾","PROFILE":"à¤Ÿà¥à¤°à¥‡à¤¨à¥€","AGE":"à¥¨à¥«","ADDRESS":"à¤˜à¥à¤¹à¤¶à¤¿à¤…à¤¬à¤¦","ID":"103","PHONE NUMBER":"à¥®à¥¨à¥­à¥©à¥¬à¥ªà¥«à¥«à¥§à¥¦","array":["name","Lamis"]},"2":{"EXPERIENCE":"à¥¦","Name":"à¤•à¥à¤¶à¤² à¤¸à¥‡à¤ ","PROFILE":"à¤Ÿà¥à¤°à¥‡à¤¨à¥€","AGE":"à¥¨à¥ª","ADDRESS":"à¤¨à¥‡à¤µ à¤¦à¥‡à¤²à¥à¤¹à¥€","ID":"102","PHONE NUMBER":"à¥¯à¥§à¥®à¥¨à¥­à¥©à¥¬à¥ªà¥«à¥¦","array":["name","Lamis"]},"1":{"EXPERIENCE":"+à¥§","Name":"à¤…à¤œà¤¯ à¤°à¤£","PROFILE":"à¤¦à¥‡à¤¸à¤¿à¤—à¥à¤¨à¥‡à¤°","AGE":"à¥¨à¥­","ADDRESS":"à¤¦à¥‡à¤²à¥à¤¹à¥€","ID":"101","PHONE NUMBER":"à¥­à¥®à¥¯à¥¯à¥®à¥­à¥¬à¥«à¥«à¥¬","array":["name","Lamis"]},"0":{"EXPERIENCE":"+à¥§","Name":"à¤°à¤¾à¤œ à¤¸à¤¿à¤‚à¤˜","PROFILE":"à¤¦à¥‡à¤µà¥‡à¤²à¥‹à¤ªà¥‡à¤°","AGE":"à¥¨à¥¬","ADDRESS":"à¤˜à¥à¤¹à¤¶à¤¿à¤…à¤¬à¤¦","ID":"100","PHONE NUMBER":"à¥¯à¥¯à¥®à¥®à¥­à¥­à¥¬à¥¬à¥«à¥«","array":["name","Lamis"]},"4":{"EXPERIENCE":"à¥¦","Name":"à¤°à¥‡à¤¨à¥‡ à¤°à¥‡","PROFILE":"à¤Ÿà¥à¤°à¥‡à¤¨à¥€","AGE":"à¥¨à¥©","ADDRESS":"à¤¨à¥‡à¤µ à¤¦à¥‡à¤²à¥à¤¹à¥€","ID":"104","PHONE NUMBER":"à¥®à¥§à¥®à¥¨à¥®à¥©à¥®à¥ªà¥®à¥«","array":["name","Lamis"]}},"Employee Details":[{"EXPERIENCE":"+à¥§","Name":"à¤°à¤¾à¤œ à¤¸à¤¿à¤‚à¤˜","PROFILE":"à¤¦à¥‡à¤µà¥‡à¤²à¥‹à¤ªà¥‡à¤°","AGE":"à¥¨à¥¬","ADDRESS":"à¤˜à¥à¤¹à¤¶à¤¿à¤…à¤¬à¤¦","ID":"100","PHONE NUMBER":"à¥¯à¥¯à¥®à¥®à¥­à¥­à¥¬à¥¬à¥«à¥«","array":["name","Lamis"]},{"EXPERIENCE":"+à¥§","Name":"à¤…à¤œà¤¯ à¤°à¤£","PROFILE":"à¤¦à¥‡à¤¸à¤¿à¤—à¥à¤¨à¥‡à¤°","AGE":"à¥¨à¥­","ADDRESS":"à¤¦à¥‡à¤²à¥à¤¹à¥€","ID":"101","PHONE NUMBER":"à¥­à¥®à¥¯à¥¯à¥®à¥­à¥¬à¥«à¥«à¥¬","array":["name","Lamis"]},{"EXPERIENCE":"à¥¦","Name":"à¤•à¥à¤¶à¤² à¤¸à¥‡à¤ ","PROFILE":"à¤Ÿà¥à¤°à¥‡à¤¨à¥€","AGE":"à¥¨à¥ª","ADDRESS":"à¤¨à¥‡à¤µ à¤¦à¥‡à¤²à¥à¤¹à¥€","ID":"102","PHONE NUMBER":"à¥¯à¥§à¥®à¥¨à¥­à¥©à¥¬à¥ªà¥«à¥¦","array":["name","Lamis"]},{"EXPERIENCE":"à¥¦","Name":"à¤°à¤¾à¤¹à¥à¤² à¤¶à¤°à¥à¤®à¤¾","PROFILE":"à¤Ÿà¥à¤°à¥‡à¤¨à¥€","AGE":"à¥¨à¥«","ADDRESS":"à¤˜à¥à¤¹à¤¶à¤¿à¤…à¤¬à¤¦","ID":"103","PHONE NUMBER":"à¥®à¥¨à¥­à¥©à¥¬à¥ªà¥«à¥«à¥§à¥¦","array":["name","Lamis"]},{"EXPERIENCE":"à¥¦","Name":"à¤°à¥‡à¤¨à¥‡ à¤°à¥‡","PROFILE":"à¤Ÿà¥à¤°à¥‡à¤¨à¥€","AGE":"à¥¨à¥©","ADDRESS":"à¤¨à¥‡à¤µ à¤¦à¥‡à¤²à¥à¤¹à¥€","ID":"104","PHONE NUMBER":"à¥®à¥§à¥®à¥¨à¥®à¥©à¥®à¥ªà¥®à¥«","array":["name","Lamis"]}],"Employee":[{"EXPERIENCE":"+à¥§","Name":"à¤°à¤¾à¤œ à¤¸à¤¿à¤‚à¤˜","PROFILE":"à¤¦à¥‡à¤µà¥‡à¤²à¥‹à¤ªà¥‡à¤°","AGE":"à¥¨à¥¬","ADDRESS":"à¤˜à¥à¤¹à¤¶à¤¿à¤…à¤¬à¤¦","ID":"100","PHONE NUMBER":"à¥¯à¥¯à¥®à¥®à¥­à¥­à¥¬à¥¬à¥«à¥«","array":["name","Lamis"]},{"EXPERIENCE":"+à¥§","Name":"à¤…à¤œà¤¯ à¤°à¤£","PROFILE":"à¤¦à¥‡à¤¸à¤¿à¤—à¥à¤¨à¥‡à¤°","AGE":"à¥¨à¥­","ADDRESS":"à¤¦à¥‡à¤²à¥à¤¹à¥€","ID":"101","PHONE NUMBER":"à¥­à¥®à¥¯à¥¯à¥®à¥­à¥¬à¥«à¥«à¥¬","array":["name","Lamis"]},{"EXPERIENCE":"à¥¦","Name":"à¤•à¥à¤¶à¤² à¤¸à¥‡à¤ ","PROFILE":"à¤Ÿà¥à¤°à¥‡à¤¨à¥€","AGE":"à¥¨à¥ª","ADDRESS":"à¤¨à¥‡à¤µ à¤¦à¥‡à¤²à¥à¤¹à¥€","ID":"102","PHONE NUMBER":"à¥¯à¥§à¥®à¥¨à¥­à¥©à¥¬à¥ªà¥«à¥¦","array":["name","Lamis"]},{"EXPERIENCE":"à¥¦","Name":"à¤°à¤¾à¤¹à¥à¤² à¤¶à¤°à¥à¤®à¤¾","PROFILE":"à¤Ÿà¥à¤°à¥‡à¤¨à¥€","AGE":"à¥¨à¥«","ADDRESS":"à¤˜à¥à¤¹à¤¶à¤¿à¤…à¤¬à¤¦","ID":"103","PHONE NUMBER":"à¥®à¥¨à¥­à¥©à¥¬à¥ªà¥«à¥«à¥§à¥¦","array":["name","Lamis"]},{"EXPERIENCE":"à¥¦","Name":"à¤°à¥‡à¤¨à¥‡ à¤°à¥‡","PROFILE":"à¤Ÿà¥à¤°à¥‡à¤¨à¥€","AGE":"à¥¨à¥©","ADDRESS":"à¤¨à¥‡à¤µ à¤¦à¥‡à¤²à¥à¤¹à¥€","ID":"104","PHONE NUMBER":"à¥®à¥§à¥®à¥¨à¥®à¥©à¥®à¥ªà¥®à¥«","array":["name","Lamis"]}]}"
```

**Pls Help Me To Find Whats Wrong In This..**

Comment: Is the client supplying an accept charset header? What is it? Conversly, is the server defining the response charset?

Comment: Is the String embedded into a html page or send as an AJAX response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the character encoding of your data. You're using one called UTF-8. But your browser thinks your using one called ISO-8859, because that's the standard for HTML when you don't tell the browser what you want. In java you can use the HttpServletResposne object to configure this information. Simply call:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Then the browser will interpret the data correctly. This is often done with a filter or another central point of the project, as today most project want to do the complete communication with UTF-8, to avoid running in the problems you face now

Answer (score 2):

`@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")`
or

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON +";charset=utf-8"})
```

This was missing in my code and now its working properly

Answer (score 1):

In your response, try using **content encoding UTF-8**.

I tried copying text from your question and saving it in a text file using notepad. It worked when I used UTF-8 encoding.

I have even tried using this text with an MVC4 project using Visual Studio 2010 with SP1.

Hope this helps!

Vivek