# How to send deferent language text over HTTP using java

Tags: java, http, http-post

Im trying to post a json from one server to another server using HTTP Connection
I have a model

```
Test{
    private String transId;
    private String msisdn;
    private String msg;
    private String senderId;
    private String customerid;
    private String customerName;
    private String actiontypes;
}
```

In **msg** filed i will send a message in deferent language templates based on requested language.

```
{"transId":null,"msisdn":null,"msg":"क्या हाल है","senderId":null,"customerid":null,"customerName":null,"actiontypes":null}
```

in the above example im sending hindi message.

Here is my code to post data

```
         GrameenVerLangRequestModel obj = new GrameenVerLangRequestModel();
         obj.setMsg("क्या हाल है");
         String responseFromGrameen = 
         notification.postVernacularMessageToGrameen(gson.toJson(obj),logger);
```

here is the post method

```
public String postVernacularMessageToGrameen(String body, Logger logger) {
        logger.info("Start-postVernacularMessageToGrameen");
        try {
            StringBuffer responsebuf = new StringBuffer();
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            
            logger.info("Data :"+body);
            System.out.println("Data :"+body);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj .openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        
            // Send post request
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            
            wr.writeBytes(body);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode == 200){
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    responsebuf.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                logger.info("Response from Server : " + responsebuf);
                return responsebuf.toString();
                } else {
                    return responseCode+"";
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.info(e);
        }finally {
        logger.info("End-postVernacularMessageToGrameen");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

here is the body before i post to another server

```
Data :{"transId":null,"msisdn":null,"msg":"क्या हाल है","senderId":null,"customerid":null,"customerName":null,"actiontypes":null}
```

after posting to the intended server where i am receiving like

```
Data received:{"transId":null,"msisdn":null,"msg":"M/> 9>2 9H","senderId":null,"customerid":null,"customerName":null,"actiontypes":null}
```

**"msg":"M/> 9>2 9H"** how to get it readable in intended language.

Can anyone help me with this ?.

Thanks.

**EDIT :**
i'm trying to decode at receiving server side as below but it gives same response

**utf8EncodedString :{"transId":null,"msisdn":null,"msg":"M/> 9>2 9H","senderId":null,"customerid":null,"customerName":null,"actiontypes":null}**

```
    String rawString = receivedData;
    ByteBuffer buffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(rawString); 
     
    String utf8EncodedString = 
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(buffer).toString();
    System.out.println("utf8EncodedString :"+utf8EncodedString);
```

Comment: Use the same character encoding you use on the requesting server on your receiving server.

Comment: sounds like encoding issues, what web server are you using. Maybe you need to add the media type and encoding the the producing attribute, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701340/want-to-have-other-language-fonthindi-in-response-through-json-using-restful-w

Comment: @crimson589 i have updated my  question with edit please check.

Comment: @Jocke i am using Restful web service.